# adding index column by date in R

Tags: r

i've got a large table with several columns that I've snipped out below.  The table was brought in through MicrosoftAccess, so the column "index" is all over the place, correlating to nothing in particular.  Basically I want to add another column to the table that indexes the rows by date oldest -> newest.  So independent of any other criteria, I want the earliest date to have "1" and go chronologically 2,3,4,5 etc. to the last date.

```
  index- effort_ID- Tag ID- SUR- Date and Time
  350162 - 244 - 92 - 10916 - 2016-12-14 19:25:00
  77850 - 243 -77- 10913 -2016-12-14 19:28:10
  77858 - 243- 79 -10913 -2016-12-14 19:39:11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your data in a better format:

```
df <- structure(list(index = c(350162, 77850, 77858), effort_ID = c(244, 
                                                                243, 243), `Tag ID` = c(92, 77, 79), SUR = c(10916, 10913, 10913
                                                                ), `Date and Time` = c("2016-12-14 19:25:00", "2016-12-14 19:28:10", 
                                                                                       "2016-12-14 19:39:11")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                       ), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Then use `lubridate` to get into date time format, `arrange` and set row index to a column from `tidyverse`

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(`Date and Time` = ymd_hms(`Date and Time`)) %>%
  arrange(`Date and Time`) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "new_index")
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  new_index  index effort_ID `Tag ID`   SUR `Date and Time`    
  <chr>      <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1 1         350162       244       92 10916 2016-12-14 19:25:00
2 2          77850       243       77 10913 2016-12-14 19:28:10
3 3          77858       243       79 10913 2016-12-14 19:39:11
```

Answer (score 0):

first arrange your df using dplyr package then add a column using mutate to index
this is easy with the pipeline operator (`%>%`)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% arrange(`Date and Time`) %>%
       mutate(new_index = 1:nrow(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `base R` solution

```
df <- df[order(df$`Date and Time`),]
df$date_index <- 1:nrow(df)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was rather simple now that it's been laid out in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

Also a possible solution without using libraries

```
 str<-c( "77858 - 243- 79 -10913 -2016-12-14 19:39:11",
         "350162 - 244 - 92 - 10916 - 2016-12-14 19:25:00",
         "77850 - 243 -77- 10913 -2016-12-14 19:28:10")

 customer<-c("lina","rita","mina")
 df <- data.frame(cust=customer,date=str)
 df

  cust                                            date
1 lina     77858 - 243- 79 -10913 -2016-12-14 19:39:11
2 rita 350162 - 244 - 92 - 10916 - 2016-12-14 19:25:00
3 mina     77850 - 243 -77- 10913 -2016-12-14 19:28:10
```

After

```
str<-as.character(substr(str,(nchar(str)+1)-19,nchar(str)))
str

"2016-12-14 19:39:11" "2016-12-14 19:25:00" "2016-12-14 19:28:10"

df$newDate=strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
rownames(df) <- order(df$newDate)
df

  cust                                            date             newDate
2 lina     77858 - 243- 79 -10913 -2016-12-14 19:39:11 2016-12-14 19:39:11
3 rita 350162 - 244 - 92 - 10916 - 2016-12-14 19:25:00 2016-12-14 19:25:00
1 mina     77850 - 243 -77- 10913 -2016-12-14 19:28:10 2016-12-14 19:28:10
```

Finally

```
df[order(as.numeric(rownames(df))),,drop=FALSE]
df
  cust                                            date             newDate
1 mina     77850 - 243 -77- 10913 -2016-12-14 19:28:10 2016-12-14 19:28:10
2 lina     77858 - 243- 79 -10913 -2016-12-14 19:39:11 2016-12-14 19:39:11
3 rita 350162 - 244 - 92 - 10916 - 2016-12-14 19:25:00 2016-12-14 19:25:00
```